# Forwarding Mails in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, incoming-mail

How can i forward mails from a particular company to Jan  who is  handling the account of  that Firm .

Is it possible with Google Apps Script ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes its possible, but a better fit is to create a gmail filter. It will be faster and wont use up quotas.

Comment: I found apps script code to retrieve the mails with particular label . how can i read all mails and get the senders email id ?

Comment: why are you not using gmail filters? also per forum guidelines, paste the code that you tried and didnt work,

Comment: What if you want to forward mails to adresses that you can't 
'confirm' (which you have to do to forward emails afaik)

Comment: in that case yes you need a script. You should still use a gmail filter to label the emails that need forwarding. The script then processes those only